# Laravel append attribute not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

My objective is to append average rating of each products so i can display in the front end

I have two tables one is `products` and another is `reviews`

My `review model`

```
class Review extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'reviews';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'product_id', 'rating', 'feedback');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }

}
```

My `product model`

```
protected $appends = ['average_rating','my_rating'];


   // i added these accoceries inside class as per the laravel documentation
 public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }


    public function getAverageRatingAttribute(){
        return round($this->reviews()->avg('rating'),1);
    }


    public function getMyRatingAttribute(){

        //check if user loged in
        if(Auth::check()){
            return round($this->reviews()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->avg('rating'),1);
        }else{
            return round($this->reviews()->where('user_id',NULL)->avg('rating'),1);
        }
    }
```

**Response**

```
 [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                    [sku_code] => 
                                    [name] => Product title
                                    [slug] => product-title
                                    [description] => This is loream ipsum text to check if the  application is working correctly or not
                                    [thumbnail] => images/products/thumbnail/a9fa0b28.jpg
                                    [short_description] => This is loream ipsum to check if update working or not
                                    [featured_image_id] => 
                                    [category_id] => 1
                                    [subcategory_id] => 
                                    [price] => 259.00
                                    [img_height] => 20
                                    [img_width] => 10
                                    [discount_id] => 
                                    [featured_product] => 0
                                    [availability] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2018-02-22 11:33:27
                                    [updated_at] => 2018-02-22 13:36:21
                                    [deleted_at] => 
                                    [weight] => 100
                                    [weight_unit] => kg
                                )
```

So basically this should append average rating to my product when ever i call from the controller.
But instead i m getting Only the fields available in product table.  I worked with this before and worked fine back then but i do not understand why it is not working this time. 
Can anyone please help me? 
thank you.

Comment: "But instead i m getting Only the fields available in product table" what do you mean ? the appended columns should not appear in the table!

Comment: plz `dd($product->average_rating)` and  `dd($product->my_rating)`

Comment: Ofcourse appended column should not appear in the table , but it should appear in the result as column of the table. But as you can see in the response its not coming. I wonder why

Comment: under "Response" section, what did you call to get this response? Did you print an instance of `Product` model? and the Response shows it's `attributes` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding about how `$appends` works. From the [official Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json):

`Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON forms.`

So it will not appear in the `attributes` list of the model if you print the model instance itself. However, the appended attribute will appear in the results of `$model->toArray()` and `$model->toJson()`. It will also be accessible using `$model->appended_attribute` (or `$model->average_rating` in your case).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that...couldn't figure out why the attribute wasn't showing up in tinker. toJson(), toArray() shows the new attribute and $model->custom_attribute returns its value exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is getting data like this `$product->my_rating` and `$product->average_rating`. as suggested by @tykus at laracast

https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-append-attribute-not-working